# Proving limit does not exist (multivariable caculus)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that the limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} y\sin(1/x)$$

does not exist.

I am absolutely lost. I am not sure if I can substitute $(x,y)$ for another function such as $y=x-1,$ leading to the limit being:

$$\lim_{(x-1)\to(1)} (x-1)\sin(1/x)$$

but I think this just complicates things more.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that $(x,y)$ isn't approaching $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. You can construct a sequence $a_{n}$ for which $\sin (1/a_{n}) \equiv 1$ and another $b_n$ for which $\sin (1/b_{n}) \equiv 0$.

> $a_n = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi}$
>
> $b_n = \dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$

These different ways to go to zero makes the limit to "take" two different values, $1$ and $0$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Show that the limit of the function at that point does not exist by going along $y=1.$ Can you now see how to proceed?